# trouble with configuring keyboard functionality on a form field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

l have 16 input elements to enter a subscription key

[image]

so I managed to write code that if the user enters a character it automatically goes to the next blank input just like the apple verification but when deleting it deletes starting from the previous element and ignores the currently focused

[image]

```
// this is my state with a NodeList of all the 16 input elements shown in the picture
const [elems, setElems] = React.useState([]);

// this is the function that automatically focuses the next field after a keyDown event or delete and its supposed to delete and focuses the previous element 
 const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
   const elIndex = +event.target.getAttribute("data-carrier");
   if (event.target.value.length <= 1 && event.code === "Backspace") {
       elems[elIndex > 0 ? elIndex - 1 : elIndex].focus();
    } else {
       if (event.target.value.length === 1) {
           return elems[elIndex < 15 ? elIndex + 1 : elIndex].focus();
        } else {
          return (elems[elIndex].value = "");
       }
   }
 };

    
//this my JSX and array is a user defined function that returns an array with 16 entries which are numbers
array(16).map((count) => (
   <AppInput
      dataCarrier={count}
      key={count}
      onKeyDown={handleKeyDown }
    />
 ))
```

Comment: You may need to prevent the default behavior of the backspace key and just code what you want to happen. Set the target value to "" then move the focus to the previous field. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: thanks, @Glenn it's now working